# UIButton not reponding iOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I am a rookie iOS programmer, so I don't really know where I am going wrong.

I am using Xcode 4.5.1.
I added a UIButton to my view and added an IBAction for that button.
On iOS 6 it works perfectly, but on iOS 5 the button just does not respond.
I need to press the button for a really long time and only then it 
calls the IBAction.

I am not sure if Apple changed anything with iOS 6.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of you linking the items in IB and any relevant code?

Comment: I am sure that it is a very simple fix. But without code it is impossible to conclude what your problem actually is

Comment: I am sorry for not including any code or screenshots.
I figured out the problem. I had added a tap recognizer on the view, which was interfering with the tap for the button. 

As soon as i removed that, it worked perfectly. Thanks for your comments guys and i again apologize for not putting in any code. 
I'll make sure i do it next time.

Comment: Don't understand why this was closed. This just solved my issue!!!!

Comment: Same here but I need to keep the tap recognizer.. Any idea how to have both at the same time?